# The best way to sort divs with a lot of content on the html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, javascript-objects

Below is this html code structure. For the purpose of sorting, you may add any "id=", classes or data attributes to any tags. Each block (any tag in it) can be supplemented with its unique string identifier such as `<div class="c1" id="uniqueid">`. Initially, the page is generated in unsorted order. When you click on the button on the page, these div blocks `<div class="c1">` should be sorted by the value in `<span id="sort">...</span>` in ascending, descending and exactly the same unsorted order as they were before sorting. They must be sorted and of course their position on the page should change. The number of `<div class="c1">` blocks can be as many as 1000.

```
<div class="global">

    <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">
            <img src="https://www.example.com/i1.jpg">
            <a href="/a1">a1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="c3">
            <span>Text</span>
            <a href="/a2">a2</a>
            <a href="/a3">a3</a>
            <div>
                <div class="c4">Text <span id="sort">100</span> <img src="https://www.example.com/i2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="c5">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="c6">Text <a href="/a4"><img src="https://www.example.com/i3.jpg"></a></div>
                <div class="c7">500</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">
            <img src="https://www.example.com/i1.jpg">
            <a href="/a1">a1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="c3">
            <span>Text</span>
            <a href="/a2">a2</a>
            <a href="/a3">a3</a>
            <div>
                <div class="c4">Text <span id="sort">50</span> <img src="https://www.example.com/i2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="c5">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="c6">Text <a href="/a4"><img src="https://www.example.com/i3.jpg"></a></div>
                <div class="c7">500</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">
            <img src="https://www.example.com/i1.jpg">
            <a href="/a1">a1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="c3">
            <span>Text</span>
            <a href="/a2">a2</a>
            <a href="/a3">a3</a>
            <div>
                <div class="c4">Text <span id="sort">150</span> <img src="https://www.example.com/i2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="c5">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="c6">Text <a href="/a4"><img src="https://www.example.com/i3.jpg"></a></div>
                <div class="c7">500</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

What is the best way to do the sorting here? I would appreciate an example.

Comment: The best approach would be to do this with javascript. If you are not sure on how to write it yourself, there should be a lot of plugins available such as: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: @battaboombattabaam, Please remove your comment.

Comment: For a person  who has minus this question. I need your explanation of what's wrong with the question. Please don't put a minus without an explanation.

Comment: Asking for the best way to do sth. will most likely lead to opinion based answers, which is not wanted. Try to implement the sort yourself and then ask about specific problems. Thats most likely why you got downvoted.

Comment: @williamzo I hadn't downvoted your question, but if you'd want me to. You haven't tried anything, all I did was point you to a direction where you could look into. You can't just simply ask anyone to write you the entire part of code without making the least effort in trying. Apologies if this sounds bad. Keep trying and stay motivated.

Comment: @Lapskaus, I've made some nonsense. So I didn't write it here.

Comment: @battaboombattabaam, I've made some nonsense. So I didn't write it here. I didn't ask for a link to the plugins. The plugin can't answer my questions. Anyway, thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code comparing according to int values of spans. You can change comparator function according to your needs.

```js
const $c1_list = $('.c1').detach();
$c1_list.sort(function(el1, el2){
 return parseInt($(el1).find('#sort').text()) > parseInt($(el2).find('#sort').text()) ? 1 : -1;
});
$('.global').append($c1_list);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="global">

    <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">
            <img src="https://www.example.com/i1.jpg">
            <a href="/a1">a1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="c3">
            <span>Text</span>
            <a href="/a2">a2</a>
            <a href="/a3">a3</a>
            <div>
                <div class="c4">Text <span id="sort">100</span> <img src="https://www.example.com/i2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="c5">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="c6">Text <a href="/a4"><img src="https://www.example.com/i3.jpg"></a></div>
                <div class="c7">500</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">
            <img src="https://www.example.com/i1.jpg">
            <a href="/a1">a1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="c3">
            <span>Text</span>
            <a href="/a2">a2</a>
            <a href="/a3">a3</a>
            <div>
                <div class="c4">Text <span id="sort">50</span> <img src="https://www.example.com/i2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="c5">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="c6">Text <a href="/a4"><img src="https://www.example.com/i3.jpg"></a></div>
                <div class="c7">500</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">
            <img src="https://www.example.com/i1.jpg">
            <a href="/a1">a1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="c3">
            <span>Text</span>
            <a href="/a2">a2</a>
            <a href="/a3">a3</a>
            <div>
                <div class="c4">Text <span id="sort">150</span> <img src="https://www.example.com/i2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="c5">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="c6">Text <a href="/a4"><img src="https://www.example.com/i3.jpg"></a></div>
                <div class="c7">500</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working great! Before asking the question, I tried to use arrays and sort them. Your solution works and works much better.